# Cannot resolve symbol IPAddressUtil

Tags: android, inetaddress

I have a problem in my android studio(macosx) :
in `InetAddress.java` some import have problem

```
import sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil;

import android.system.GaiException;

import android.system.StructAddrinfo;

import libcore.io.Libcore;
```

editor says

> cannot resolve symbol IPAddressUtil

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think those classes are not in Android SDK (IpAddressUtil, Libcore). Also, it is [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) to use classes from `sun.*` package in your programs.